# Fibonacci Sequence Formula Query

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I have this code

```
for(int Variable=2; Variable<N; Variable++)
{
    Answer = b + c;
    b = c;
    c = Answer;
}
```

And it works for calculating the answer when with all my other for code. However the code above I don't understand how it works....Just looking for an explanation on how it gives the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just write down what that loop does for e.g. N=5?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I have tested the program and it works. Just dont understand how. As I declared earlier that b = 1 and c = 1.
Dont get this part either "Variable<N; Variable++"

Comment: @Craig If that's the part you don't get, you need to pick up an introductory C++ book *quickly*.

Comment: This is an example in the sheets for our lecture, we just started C++ moving from VB, so just trying to get my head round it thats all.

Comment: Refer to the C++ Textbook of your choice and look up the chapters "variable definition" and "for loop" to understand the syntax.

Comment: So is it the Fibonacci Formula algorithm you are asking help for or the construction of a for-loop?

Comment: Algorithm essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily, you have to understand, how does the Fibonacci sequence looks like and how it is built. I won't discuss it here, seek for it on the Internet. Then try to write down on a piece of paper the values of Answer, b and c on each loop's step, eg.

```
Variable | Answer  b  c
---------+-------------
(before) |   1     1  1
       2 |   2     1  2
       3 |   3     2  3
       4 |   5     3  5
```

...and so on.

Then seek for resemblance of the values of this "paper-debugging" to definition of Fibonacci sequence and all shall became clear.

---

**Edit:**

I understand, that you have problems with understanding scope of variable? If you declare a variable in a code block denoted by `{` and `}` braces, it will be visible and modifyable everywhere within this block.

```
{    
    {
        int b = 1, c = 1, Answer = 0;
        for(int Variable=2; Variable<N; Variable++)
        {
            // The b and c variables are visible here
            // and can be both read and written.

            Answer = b + c;
            b = c;
            c = Answer;
        }
    } 

    // However, they are no longer visible here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I kind of get that now. I just didn't get how the values of b and c changed if I declared above;

unsigned long long b = 1, c = 1, Answer;

Just wasn't sure how b and c values changed constantly, depending on N.

Comment: Try to ask questions more clearly. I couldn't get, what your problem actually was from the beginning.

Comment: Ah thanks! That makes sense! Sorry, complete novice, just started so wasn't really sure what was going on. Here is my understanding of the basics; 

unsigned long long - to make sure the limits are correct i.e. the answers don't become wrong/negaitve when dealing wiht large values

Variable ++ - The increment, working up to the value of N?

Variable = 2 - as the first two declared values are 1, needs to start at the next value above

Its just the variable<N I can't explain.

Comment: And apologies for the vagueness of the question, will try work it better next time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will help. As the code iterates over Fibonacci numbers, `c` is the most recent number and `b` is number immediately before that.

Comment: But if above I declared, 

" unsigned long long b = 1, c = 1, Answer;"

how does that work ?